# Referencias filhas e service pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd

Um pattern muito usado em `DDD`, é o `service pattern`.

Minha dúvida é, aonde fica a lógica para referencias "filhas"?

Por exemplo, um caso de uso, `Pedido` que possui `Produtos`

```
public class Pedido 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int ClienteId {get;set;}
  public Cliente Cliente {get;set;}
  public ICollection<PedidoProduto> Produtos {get;set;}
}

public class PedidoProduto
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int PedidoId {get;set;}
  public int ProdutoId {Get;set;}

  public Pedido Pedido {get;set;}
  public Produto Produto {get;set;}
}
```

Vamos à uma Action do Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Pedido model, int[] Produtos) 
{
   //Lógica...
}
```

Pois bem... a lógica de manipular o pedido e seus Produtos, vai dentro do `PedidoService`, logo deixando apenas o meu `Controller` dependencia com apenas 1 `Service`, e dentro do `PedidoService` ter a dependencia de `PedidoRepository` e `ProdutoRepository`, ou há a necessidade de criar 2 `Service` e fazer o `Controller` ter a dependencia dos 2 `Service`?

Comment: Excelente pergunta. Como a resposta é longa, chegando em casa eu vou responder com calma, mas basicamente, seu controller deve ter dependência apenas com o PedidoService ou qualquer outra classe que contenha as regras de negócio, você tem que imaginar a ação de criar um pedido como uma ação atômica. Neste caminho, seu teste unitário conseguirá de maneira mais fácil emular mais de um cenário.

Comment: @wryel estarei aguardando..:) É que muitos falam sobre acoplamento, e que DDD "resolve" alguns casos...usando DI por ex, mas aí que está...Quando trabalhamos com models, que contenham muitos vinculos (ICollection), quem deve ter maior acoplamento? o controller com vários services? Ou um service com vários repository? rsrs...

Comment: Quando tive esse "problema", eu criei vários services no controller, não sei se é o melhor modo, mas funcionava de boa. vamos ver o que o @wryel sugere.

Answer (score 1):

O cenário que você apresenta, é um cenário de um **Agregado**, então a lógica deve sempre ser chamada a partir do **Service** de Pedido, o serviço do pedido tem acesso aos seus itens.
E não faz muito sentido você poder chamar os itens do pedido de forma separada do pedido.

Answer (score 0):

Boa pergunta. O responsável pela parte pesada da lógica deve ser o Service, a ideia do Service Pattern é agrupar um conjunto de operações de um determinado contexto e disponibiliza-las através da sua interface para as camadas clientes, neste caso ele que deve ter N Repository. 
Imagine uma aplicação que deve ser consumida por diferentes formas, como um serviço REST e por Socket, por exemplo, os Services ofereceriam em suas interfaces as operações da aplicação de forma que os clientes (REST e Socket) tratariam questões pertinentes ao seu protocolo.

Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)